# GUI doesn't appear Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

Hi I am creating a program and I encountered an error when running it. It says:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1045)
            at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:365)
            at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.add(JPopupMenu.java:264)
            at javax.swing.JMenu.add(JMenu.java:562)
            at truthtable.GUI.getCreatedMenuBar(GUI.java:587)
            at truthtable.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:208)
            at truthtable.Application.<init>(Application.java:10)
            at truthtable.Application.main(Application.java:18)
    Java Result: 1
```

My class Application.java:

```
  package truthtable;
    public class Application {

        public Application() {
            new GUI(null);
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            new Application();
        }
    }
```

What does this mean?  And when i tried to edit the code in that error, it is readonly.

This is my code for gui constructor :

```
 public GUI(final ApplicationStarter appStarter) {
        super();

        this.applicationStarter = appStarter;
        outputMode = TruthValue.TRUE_FALSE;
        computationMethod = COMPLETE_METHOD;
        hasFullPermission = getHasFullPermission();
        smallTableLimit = 256;
        maxStatementLength = 256;
        maxRowsInTextTable = 1024;

      int arraySize=3;

        buttonStates = new boolean[4];
        final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        defaultCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
        waitCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
                int width = getWidth(),
                    height = getHeight();

                final int minHeight=50;
                final int minWidth=20;
                if (width < minWidth)
                    width = minWidth;
                if (height < minHeight)
                    height = minHeight;
                setSize(width, height);
            }
```

Comment: Can we see the code for gui? The error is probably in there. The only thing from your code that I see is a "null" for new Gui but without knowing GUI's code I can't tell if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: why do you pass your GUI null?  yuck.

Comment: For better help sooner, post one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (rather than several code snippets).

Comment: I don't see any `setVisible(true)` calls.

Comment: Can we see this: `truthtable.GUI.getCreatedMenuBar(GUI.java:587)`

Comment: @RyanAmos  fileMenu.add(exportMenu);

Comment: @AndrewThompson how to post a SSCCCE?sorry I'm just a newbie here :)

Comment: By 'post' I guess you mean 'prepare' or 'make'.  The details are in the document at the end of the link.  Ask a question if you do not understand anything in that document.  I am well placed to answer.  :)

Comment: @AlvinPulido What? I don't think that will show the GUI. show() and setVisible(true) will.

Comment: @RyanAmos where should I put the setvisible or show?

Comment: @AlvinPulido use setVisible(true) when you want your GUI to appear. Probably at the end of the constructor, but if you're having a null pointer exception, it probably won't reach that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running the wrong program. You need a GUI constructor to go with it.

Comment: The issue is that he's not showing us everything. This is his program, but not enough of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the GUI constructor that you don't show code for.  It looks like passing null will be a problem.  Is it expecting a non-null value?  If yes, figure out how to provide one.